# Where do I get data on newly formed businesses in the US?

Tags: data-request, usa, business

Is there a gov API or dataset that I can get, on newly formed businesses? Data like biz name, address, tax ID, owner name, type of business (restaurant, laundromat...) etc?

Comment: localities typically print this information; sba does annual reports but not to the detail you desire.

Comment: I believe "business licenses" (sometimes called "business registrations") are issued at the State Level, so you might poke around www.state.xx.us where xx is a two letter state abbreviation (most states redirect this to something like newmexico.gov, but the 'state.xx.us' format should still work.

Comment: @BarryCarter can you explain that format some more? http://state.va.us/ doesn't work for me.

Comment: It appears my information is outdated. See 2nd paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us#States_and_territories for a reference, but, yes, it appears to be "broken" for VA and maybe others.

Comment: census has business formation surveys, but the data doesn't contain the details you desire. https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/bfs/data/datasets.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use https://www.crunchbase.com

You can search for companies and filter as you need (it is limited for free use though).

[image]